# Can a caster of Dispel Magic just target a specific spell on a creature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Dispel Magic says (emphasis mine):

> Choose **one creature**, object, **or magical effect** within range. Any spell of 3rd level or lower on the target ends. For each spell of 4th level or higher on the target, make an ability check using your spellcasting ability. The DC equals 10 + the spell's level. On a successful check, the spell ends.

At high level play, I've found that players often have long-term buff spells in effect (i.e. *Heroes Feast*, *Mindblank*, etc.), which are a major factor in them being able to survive.

If one of these characters is affected by a save or suck kind of spell (i.e. *Mental Prison*, *Irresistable Dance*, etc.), the need to remove that spell becomes imperative.

**With this in mind, can a caster of *Dispel Magic* target only a negative spell under the assumption that it is a discrete 'magical effect' subject to removal? Or must they target the 'creature' and risk removing all spells, both positive and negative?**

For reference, we see a potentially unique 'magical effect' in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/179641/31402) about Yeenoghu's flail. This effect is similar to a spell in its function (target is affected by the *Confusion* spell if they fail the save), but has clear differences from a spell because the spell would require Yeenoghu's concentration and have a different duration. Conversely, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/152991/31402) suggests that a 'magical effect' only applies to things that wholly separated from the creature.

Comment: At least related: [How exactly does the Dispel Magic spell work with multiple effects?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/111997)

Comment: Dupe?: [How can you selectively dispel spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/167962)

Comment: @Someone_Evil Looks like a dupe to me.

Comment: @Someone_Evil I think you're correct, but I want to make sure there isn't something in that question regarding spell level that would potentially make this question unique.

Comment: @Pyrotechnical This statement from the bountied answer there seems like a pretty level take: "It is a safe assumption that Dispel Magic doesn't wildly change how it works when casted at a higher level."